# If exists, return the document, otherwise create new one - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am too new to MongoDB. I wanted to do both operation in one. The problem is as following:

Let's say I have an array of documents in mongodb.

```
[
   {
      id: "someId1",
      name: "John"
   },
   {
      id: "someId2",
      name: "Doe"
   }
]
```

I want to make an operation where I will search with value `someId1` in all documents. if any document's `id` key matches with the searched value, that document must be returned, otherwise new document must be created.

I have tried to do first `collection.find({id: "someId1"})`.
If it returns null, means no document exists, then proceed to the `collection.insertOne({id: "someId1", name: "John"})`.
If it returns the document, did further stuffs.

Hope I could explain my problem. Thank You!